# explicit конструктор копирования используемый для методов требующих неявного приведения

Tags: c++

Следующая структура не скомпилируется:

```
struct A {
    explicit A() {}
    explicit A(const A&) {}

     ~ A() {}
    const A some(const A &a) {return A();}

};
```

вернется ошибка:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'A::A(A)'
 const A some(const A &a) {return A();}
```

ни как не могу понять, что я забыл? если убрать explicit A(const A&) {}, то компилятор сам создаст необходимые конструкторы, что бы все заработало, вот только мне надо понять каких не хватает.

Comment: [не воспроизводится](https://godbolt.org/z/bjh9oq)

Comment: Не пишите везде, где не нужно, explicit. Какой в нем глубокий смысл в конструкторе копирования? Как только вы его уберете, GCC полегчает :) - https://ideone.com/bXbw62

Comment: воспроизводится при --std=c++14 и ранее

Comment: понимаю, что можно без explicit, но все же хотелось бы понять, что именно требует компилятор. Это синтетическая задача для того что бы разобраться в теме

Comment: Какое отношение этот вопрос имеет к "методам, возвращающим const значение"? Никакой связи с наличием `const` в типе возвращаемого значения тут нет.

Comment: Да, я исправил, в начале не понимал источник проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До C++17 этот код будет нерабочим так как `return A();` потребует неявного вызова `explicit` конструктора копирования. В С++17 же в таком случае конструкторы копирования и перемещения приниматься во внимание не будут (даже если они объявлены как `deleted`) и будет вызван только конструктор по-умолчанию.